# Request.UrlReferrer shows current url not the referrer

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I want to display the referrer URL in a label in an ASP.NET web application. I use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the referrer url. When I want to write it in an label I use `ToString();`

When I run the program in `site1.aspx` and referrer to `nextpage.aspx` the label on `nextpage.aspx` shows me `http://localhost:1891/NextPage.aspx`.

What's wrong with my code?

My Code on the site `nextpage.aspx` is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LabelBrowserInfos.Text = Request.Browser.Browser.ToString();
     LabelBrowserCookies.Text = Request.Cookies.Count.ToString();
     LabelHTTPMethod.Text = Request.HttpMethod.ToString();
     LabelQueryString.Text = Request.QueryString.ToString();
     if (Request.UrlReferrer != null) 
         LabelURL.Text = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
```

I have to use the version with reading the Request methods, other functions are not allowed.

I redirect to `nextpage.aspx` with the following code:

```
protected void bMoveNextPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ListItems"] = lbItems.Items;
    Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Can you **show us** your actual code?

Comment: How you are navigating from site1.aspx to nextpage.aspx? If you're using Server.Transfer,check this http://www.ehow.com/how_12217131_return-previous-after-servertransfer.html

Comment: @malkam I am not allowed to use server.transfer. I redirect with `Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");`

Comment: Where is the code that performs the redirect (i.e. add it)? Also all of those `ToString`s are pointless. Those things are already strings.

Comment: @AntP: also added the redirect code. It is a simple `Response.Redirect`